# Filter dynamic graph from input data with ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, charts, filtering

I have made the code to draw a graph using the data obtained from a query in the database.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
```

PHP

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(social_id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(login_at, '%d-%m') as datee
FROM social_users_connections
WHERE login_at < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 MONTH)
AND client_id = $clientID
GROUP BY datee
ORDER BY login_at");

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}


//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();
// print_r($data);
//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: "view/ajax/php/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var player = [];
            var score = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                player.push(data[i].total);
                score.push(data[i].datee);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: score,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Client Connections',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 0)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 1)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 0)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 1)',
                    data: player
                }]

            };

            var chartOptions = {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 80,
                        fontColor: 'black'
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                            color: "black"
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Fecha"
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "black",
                            borderDash: [2, 5]
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Número de conexiones"
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 5
                        }
                    }]
                }
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata,
                options: chartOptions
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Result:
[image]

What I need to do is add 2 input for the user to choose two dates and show a certain range. I tried to pass the input values through ajax to the PHP script to change the query but without success.

I tried this too:
HTML:

```
<input class="text-center" name="filter_date_from" type="date" id="filter_date_from" placeholder="fecha">
                <input class="text-center" name="filter_date_to" type="date" id="filter_date_to" placeholder="fecha">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="filterGraph()">Filtrar</button>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
    function filterGraph() {
        var datefrom = document.getElementById('filter_date_from').value;
        var dateto = document.getElementById('filter_date_to').value;
        Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "view/ajax/php/data_filter.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
                datefrom :  datefrom,
                dateto : dateto
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var player = [];
                var score = [];

                for (var i in data) {
                    player.push(data[i].total);
                    score.push(data[i].datee);
                }

                var chartdata = {
                    labels: score,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Client Connections',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 0)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 1)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 0)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 158, 251, 1)',
                        data: player
                    }]

                };

                var chartOptions = {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        labels: {
                            boxWidth: 80,
                            fontColor: 'black'
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                color: "black"
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "Fecha"
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                color: "black",
                                borderDash: [2, 5]
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "Número de conexiones"
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                stepSize: 5
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                };

                var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options: chartOptions
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$date_from = $_POST['datefrom'];
$date_to = $_POST['dateto'];
$from = date('d-m', $date_from);
$to = date('d-m', $date_to);


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(social_id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(login_at, '%d-%m') as datee
FROM social_users_connections
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(login_at, '%d-%m') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
AND client_id = '$clientID'
GROUP BY datee
ORDER BY login_at");
echo $result;
//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}


//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();
// print_r($data);
//now print the data
print json_encode($data)
```

;

But i have this error y at console:

GET http://35.177.140.48/view/ajax/php/data_filter.php?datefrom=2018-04-01&dateto=2018-04-26 500 (Internal Server Error)

I hope someone can guide me on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot fix the broken part of your code, because you haven't posted it.  If you do not provide your php coding attempt, your question is likely to be closed as Too Broad.  StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Please offer a better description of the error the 500 error doesn't isolate very well.  What is in your error logs?  Also, I don't know how trustworthy `$ClientID` is but perhaps at least cast the value as `(int)` before using it in the query.  (I recommend prepared statements when ever using user-supplied or untrustworthy data in queries.